# How to run a executable file in c++ in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to run an executable file within a c++ code. It compiles and run, but it displays a message "permission denied". This same code works on windows, I just use the appropriate file path.

Here is the code I am using

```
FILE *fp = popen("/home/Int_Outputs/bin/Debug","r");
if (fp == NULL){
std::cout <<"Popen is null" << std::endl;
}
char buff[50];
fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),fp);
std::cout << buff;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: but how do I do that, I went to the properties of the executable file of the project and that is the path that shows

Comment: First of all, open console an type: `cd /home/Int_Outputs/bin` and then `sudo chmod u+r Debug`. If that changes nothing, explain what exactly *does not work*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the POSIX permissions for that file?
To find out, open a terminal shell and do:

```
$ ls -l /home/Int_Outputs/bin/Debug
```

You have to make sure that the UID/GID that your application runs as has permission to read the file "/home/Int_Outputs/bin/Debug"

Comment: well, I am able to run it from the terminal by doing "./Int_Outputs"

Comment: @user5231043: Really? The question implies that `Int_Outputs` is a directory, and the application is called `Debug`.

Comment: Ok, never mind I just saw my mistake, I am missing "Int_Outputs" after "Debug" since that is the executable file and Debug is just the folder.